# Wordpress getting current category ID

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to get the current ID of the category page I'm viewing.

I had checked [the_category_ID](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_category_ID)

But this echo'd my result when I used

```
<?php $catID = the_category_ID(); ?>
```

Is there a way to get it to return the value to the variable so its hidden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This writes the variable instead of echoing

```
<?php $catID = the_category_ID($echo=false);?>
```

Comment: Function is deprecated.

Comment: You should use global $cat instead.

Answer (score 48):

The current category ID is in the global `$cat` variable, when you are in a category page.

You can test it with:

```
<?php echo "Current Category ID is: " . $cat ;?>
```

when you are in for example this page `http://example.com/category/test`

Answer (score 8):

Try the following

`$catID = get_query_var( 'cat' );`

Answer (score 8):

```
$category= get_queried_object();
echo $category->term_id;
```

Comment: This is a different approach to everyone else's answer. Care to add some explanation? Also, use the code block when putting code in your post.

Comment: This is the best answer that actually works. Nice job.

Answer (score 5):

`the_category_ID` was [deprecated in 2003](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_category_ID).

Try this:

```
if (is_category()) {
    $category = get_category(get_query_var('cat'));
    $cat_id = $category->cat_ID;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Function `the_category_ID` is deprecated. You need to use `get_the_category()` function instead. E.g.:

```
$category = get_the_category(); 
echo $category[0]->cat_name;
```

See more at wordpress codex: [get_the_category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category)

Comment: of the many codes I try, the code is successful. if wan get Cat-ID, change ->cat_name with ->cat_ID. Thank

Answer (score 3):

This code current to get Category ID:

```
<?php
$category = get_the_category(); 
echo $category[0]->cat_ID;
?>
```

It's work for me, today 18 Oct 2016.

Answer (score -3):

You will get current category id in variable,

```
<?php $catID = the_category_ID($echo);?>
```

This not print directly, whenever give print statment that time only print.

Comment: Function is deprecated.