# Wordpress - get category ID and echo link accordingly

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm completely new to PHP and trying to make changes to a single post page, so that a different go-back-link will be displayed according to the category which the post belongs to.

This is what I have so far, I don't get an error but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<?php
    if ( ! empty ( $menu ) ) {
      echo '<nav class="top-bar">';
      echo '<section class="top-bar-section">';
      echo blahlab_value($menu);
      echo '</section>';
      echo '<div class="four spacing"></div>';
      echo '</nav>';
    } 
    elseif ( $cat == 9 ) {
  ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>#service-section" class="back-to-blog"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-left"></i> Back to all current work</a>
  <?php
    }
    else {
  ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>#blog-section" class="back-to-blog"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-left"></i> Back to all events</a>
  <?php
    }
  ?>
```

Many thanks!

Comment: What does it display?

Comment: It displays the link that is under the else statement.  
I basically added this part:  
elseif ( $cat == 9 ) { ?> <a href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>#service-section" class="back-to-blog"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-left"></i> Back to all current work</a> <?php }

Comment: How do you get `$cat`. Have you tried echoing cat and see its value?

Comment: Oops.. I get nothing. I got the info from [another thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228823/wordpress-getting-current-category-id), that `$cat` is a global variable. I suppose I need a function that gives the current category ID, but have no clue how to add it in the existing code and use it in my statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here you `$cat` is empty , so that it would not equate to 9.

You need to supply a function to `$cat` which will give out the current category page id. Use the below code to get category ID.If you are adding these code in single category page, add these at top of your code

```
$cat = get_query_var( 'cat' );
```

These will give the `$cats` desired value and you will be able to make it work properly

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it doesn't work unfortunately. There are no errors and the back link remains the one in the `else` statement. Please note that this code is in the single.php page, which displays a single post.

Comment: Ok, can you say me where are you placing these code?

Comment: At the top of my single.php page file, between `<?php ?>` of course